# Sitemesh3 + Freemarker, only body not rendering

Tags: struts2, freemarker, sitemesh

I have tried alot but no success. **Only body is not rendering**. All the includes are merged properly in decorator. See Result Page.

**Specs**

```
jdk = 1.7
struts2 = 2.3.4.1
sitemesh = 3.0-alpha-2
```

**Result Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body id="public">
        <div class="container">
            No Body
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**sitemesh3.xml**

```
<sitemesh>
    <mapping decorator="/WEB-INF/decorators/main.ftl"/>
</sitemesh>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>Struts2 SiteMesh Freemarker Web Application</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sitemesh-freemarker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.freemarker.FreemarkerDecoratorServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>TemplatePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>default_encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>ISO-8859-1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sitemesh-freemarker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.ftl</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Struts2_SiteMesh3_FreeMarker</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Struts2_SiteMesh3_FreeMarker WebApp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <struts2.version>2.3.4.1</struts2.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.6</slf4j.version>
        <sitemesh.version>3.0-alpha-2</sitemesh.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Start Slf4j-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--End Slf4j-->

        <!-- Start struts2 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End struts2 dependencies -->

        <!-- Start SiteMesh dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-sitemesh-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sitemesh</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>${sitemesh.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End SiteMesh dependencies -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Struts2_SiteMesh3_FreeMarker</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

**decorator**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <#include "../include/meta.ftl">
    </head>
    <body id="public">
        <#include "../include/navigation.ftl">
        <div class="container">
            <#include "../include/search.ftl">
            ${body}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.ftl**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta name='description' content='A simple page'>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello <strong>world</strong>!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Project Structure**

[image: project]

Comment: After alot of experimentation concluded that Sitemesh3 doesn't support Freemarker. JSP & Static support is 100% working. PLEASE post if anyone have solution.

Comment: As an aside you could try tiles. I would recommend going with tiles 3.

Comment: @quaternion, any help with this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427495/error-with-struts2-tiles3-0-0-when-navigate-from-index

Answer (score 1):

add servlet freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet to web xml at `<url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>` and use `<sitemesh:write property='body'/>` instead of `${body}` in your decorator.ftl