# error with Struts2 & Tiles3.0.0 when navigate from index

Tags: struts2, tiles

Tried my best but no success. `Index action is loaded fine but when I navigate to test than error is generated`. Not sure why this is happening.

```
Using struts2 = 2.3.4.1
Tomcat latest
Tiles = 3.0.0
```

**Pom.xml**

```
 <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <struts2.version>2.3.4.1</struts2.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.6</slf4j.version>
        <tiles.version>3.0.0</tiles.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Start Slf4j-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--End Slf4j-->

        <!--Start Struts2-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--End Struts2-->

        <!-- Start Tiles dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-ognl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- End Tiles dependencies -->

    </dependencies>
```

**struts.xml**

```
 <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="tiles-default">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" default="true" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>
        <default-action-ref name="index"/>
        <action name="index" class="com.myapp.tiles.action.Test">
            <result type="tiles">/welcome.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="test" class="com.myapp.tiles.action.Test">
            <result type="tiles">test</result>
        </action>

        <action name="/**" class="com.myapp.tiles.action.Test">
            <result>{1}</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

**Tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions >
    <definition  name="mainlayout" template="/templates/mainlayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="meta" value="/templates/main/meta.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="title" value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/templates/main/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="search" value="/templates/main/search.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="navigation" value="/templates/main/navigation.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/templates/main/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="/welcome.tiles" extends="mainlayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome To Person Management System"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/index.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="test" extends="mainlayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" expression="OGNL:title" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/index.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="WILDCARD:package/*" extends="mainlayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="{1}" type="string"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/test.jsp"/>
    </definition>



</tiles-definitions>
```

**ERROR**

```
Nov 17, 2012 8:28:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/tiles/TilesContainer;
    at org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:100)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Project structure**

[image: Tiles]

Comment: You didn't follow my integration guide ;) I see you are using the struts2 tiles plugin when trying to use tiles-3 (the tiles api has changed and so the plugin will not work with a tiles version greater than 2.2.2, so using the plugin is not an option)... try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337938/how-to-integrate-struts-2-with-tiles-3/13338099#13338099 it really is pretty easy. If you get stuck please ask.

Comment: @quaternion, Thanks. https://repository.apache.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~struts2-tiles-plugin . There is 3.0-SNAPSHOT for struts tiles plugin. But not working for me. I look into your solution.

Comment: @quaternion, Perfect. Worked. Is that 3.0-SNAPSHOT for any use?

Comment: At this time I don't think so. Hopefully in the not to far future the next plugin will use tiles-3 by default. The api's will probably stay consistent. You can now use OGNL by prefixing expressions with OGNL: that might be useful to you. See tiles 3 documentation for details on other expression types (wildcard, regex,...)

Answer (score -1):

First check your lib for duplicate or conflicting jars. As you are using maven try use plugin to check duplicate dependencies.

Second give Tiles 2.x.x a try. I never integrated Struts 2 and Tiles but met several No Class found exception with Spring 3.x and Tiles 3